# Access denied for the queue that the user should have access to in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

In our stack, we have a Keycloak that generates the JWT token for our system. We configured the Keycloak to add the RabbitMQ required access for each user to the `scope` section of the JWT (each user belongs to a customer group and each customer has a separate vhost):

```
"scope": "email profile rabbitmq.write:customer1/*/* rabbitmq.read:customer1/*/*"
```

The issue is when from the frontend (using stomp) we try to connect to the RMQ we see bellow error in the RMQ logs:

```
2023-08-02 12:26:51.471470+00:00 [erro] <0.7933.0> STOMP error frame sent:
2023-08-02 12:26:51.471470+00:00 [erro] <0.7933.0> Message: access_refused
2023-08-02 12:26:51.471470+00:00 [erro] <0.7933.0> Detail: "ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'stomp-subscription-0wa7v-Ameof5juowM_5T1g' in vhost 'customer1' refused for user '14485fee-4180-454e-8137-befaec745577'"
```

I cannot understand why that user doesn't have access to that queue. In the JWT token it is mentioned that the user has access to all the queues and exchanges in that vhost, why now I am getting access denied?

BTW we use the oauth_2 backend plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating more I found out that because the way STOMP has been implemented in RMQ the user requires `rabbitmq.configure` access in addition to the `read` and `write` and after giving the user `configure` access I was able to access the data on RMQ.